# Add a key,value node to xml file under specific xPath in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have an xml File

```
<configuration>
<MetisLinks>
<add key="MetisInternal" value="https://xyz.abc.com/" />
<add key="Hermes" value="https://hermes.abc.com/" />
<add key="umar" value="https://umar.abc.com/" />
</MetisLinks>
</configuration>
```

I need to add custom key and value in this **MetisLink** node using C#. Also if it already exists than overwrite.I searched for different solution but the exact was not on internet.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should work for you:

```
string keyToAdd = "testKey";
string valueToAdd = "http://test.com";

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"D:\build.xml");

XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
XmlElement existingMatchingElement = (XmlElement)root.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("//MetisLinks/add[@key='{0}']", keyToAdd));
if (existingMatchingElement != null)
{
    existingMatchingElement.SetAttribute("value", valueToAdd);
}
else
{
    XmlNode myNode = root.SelectSingleNode("MetisLinks");
    var nodeToAdd = doc.CreateElement("add");
    nodeToAdd.SetAttribute("key", keyToAdd);
    nodeToAdd.SetAttribute("value", valueToAdd);
    myNode.AppendChild(nodeToAdd);
}

doc.Save(@"D:\build.xml");
```

I created a file at `D:\build.xml` and copied your xml there, you could place your file containing that xml anywhere and just use that path in the code